# How much disk space for MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, diskspace

I am about to setup MongoDB on AWS EC2 (Amazon Linux HVM 64bits) and implement RAID 10.

I am expecting a couple of millions of records for a system of videos on demand.

I could not find any good advice on how much disk space I should use for that instance.

The dilemma is that I can't spend too much on EBS volume right now, but if I have to add a new bigger volume in less than a year and turn the db off to move the data to that new volume, that is a problem.

For the initial stage, I was thinking 16Gb (available after RAID 10 implementation) on a t2.medium, with plan of upgrading to m4.medium and adding replica sets later.
Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Space required = bytes per record x number of records

Comment: @MattHouser that is so simple, I didn't think about it! Great and quick reply, thanks.

Comment: So db.stats() is telling me that my average object size is 145 bytes.
Let's say I aim towards 5 millions records of 200 bytes, if I get the maths right, that's just 1Gb right??

Comment: The math seems good. Your initial 16 GB would fit and would cost $1.60 per month of SSD storage in the us-east-1 region.

Comment: Actually I'm going to use 5 volumes as per this document: https://mongodb-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ecosystem/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-amazon-ec2.html

But including snapshot storage, that's only 18$/month in my region, that's good!

Thank you for your great replies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The math is pretty simple:

```
Space required = bytes per record x number of records
```

If you have an average of 145 bytes per record with an expectation of 5 million records, you can work with 1 GB of storage.

EBS storage is pretty cheap. 1 GB of SSD is $0.10 per month in us-east-1. You could allocate 5 GB for only $0.50 per month.

Also, RAID 10 is RAID 0 and RAID 1 combined. Read over this SO question regarding RAID 0 and RAID 1 configurations with EBS.

https://serverfault.com/questions/253908/is-raid-1-overkill-on-amazon-ebs-drives-in-terms-of-reliability